Difficulty w/ getting a row of images to responsively resize when there is a change in viewport
I am having difficulty with getting a row of images to responsively resize with changes in viewport. I am finding that when the screen gets more narrow the images start wrapping, or there is an awkward white space, or they don't change size (causing the user to have to scroll horizontally to see the images).
I want the row of images to responsively resize with viewport changes without wrapping or causing there to be spaces in between/adjacent to them (they should be border to border spanning the width of the screen).Wireframe representation of desired look
I will admit that I am new to web design/development (and first time posting on Stack OverFlow).
My Code


html, body, .row {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  line-height: 1.75rem !important;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.about-imgs-item {
  height: 240px; 
  width: 245px; 
  display: flex;
  object-fit: cover;
  justify-content: start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .about-imgs-item {
      display: none;
  }
}
<div class="container-fluid dev">
    <div class="row about-imgs">
        <div class="about-imgs-item">
            <img id="about-imgs-1" src="image1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="about-imgs-item">
            <img id="about-imgs-2" src="image2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="about-imgs-item">
            <img id="about-imgs-3" src="image3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="about-imgs-item">
            <img id="about-imgs-4" src="image4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="about-imgs-item">
            <img id="about-imgs-5" src="image5.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



GitHub Link to code
I have tried using the following:

flex-wrap: nowrap;
rem instead of px for image dimension
media query for setting css specific to a screen size
removing the container

However, I will note that since I am still learning all of this, I might have not used these elements in the correct manner. Thanks!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

You can just add display:flex; and flex-wrap:wrap; to the item container <div class="row about-imgs"> will remove horizontal scroll
.about-imgs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


Hi, thanks for answering! I unfortunately don't want the images to wrap either. I just want them to responsively resize as the viewport changes, but also have them stay in a horizontal row (spanning the whole width of the screen) without spaces in between them.

Problem lies with hard-coding the image sizes.
A better approach is to divide the container element into 5 equal columns:
.about-imgs { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
.about-imgs img {
  /* prevents gaps when the images 
     are too small to fill the row width
     Might produce pixelation if the images are enlarged too much!
   */
  width: 100%;
}

and simplify the markup to:
<div class="row">
  <div class="col about-imgs">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <img src="image2.jpg">
    <img src="image3.jpg">
    <img src="image4.jpg">
    <img src="image5.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

See it here.
Note: I wrapped the row contents in .col to counter the negative margins applied by .row on certain screen sizes.
